# Unable to make use of constructor to pass values from one screen to another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a stateful widget class, which has a constructor with one parameter which is used to pass the document ID. Whenever this class is called this document ID is passed as a parameter.

I need to pass this parameter as the DocumentID for the CollectionReference object, but when I try to do so I'm getting the following error.

```
class PersonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PersonPageState createState() => _PersonPageState();
}

class _PersonPageState extends State<PersonPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  String personID;
  _PersonPageState({this.personID});

  var personDetailsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('person')
      .doc(personID)
      .collection('details')
      .orderBy('recordID', descending: false);

.
.
.
```

Error:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
lib/screens/person_home.dart:30:12: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'personID'.
      .doc(personID)
           ^^^^^^^^
```

I'm fairly new to the programming, not sure what exactly is causing this issue.

Really appreciate, if anyone could help me with this. Thanks in advance.

**NEW ERROR**

now getting a different error within the Stream Builder.  `Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'personDetailsCollection'. stream: personDetails.snapshots(), ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`

Comment: Well, the first step would be to fix your copy/paste error, because the constructor should be called `_PersonPageState` and not `_CoursePageState`. Then you will need to actually fill that parameter in your Widget and move your logic into the constructor.

Comment: Thanks @nvoigt for correcting the errors, this error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting `personID` form the `State`. Instead, you should get it from `PersonPage` constructor and you can access that from `State` like this: `widget.perosnID;`

```
class PersonPage extends StatefulWidget {
PersonPage(this.personID);
String personID;
  @override
  _PersonPageState createState() => _PersonPageState();
}

class _PersonPageState extends State<PersonPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  var personDetailsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('person')
      .doc(widget.personID)
      .collection('details')
      .orderBy('recordID', descending: false);

.
.
.
```

Comment: Whats the problem?

Comment: I have added the latest error after updating the code as suggested by you, could you please look help with this. Thanks in advance.